# Predicting the product of bromination of acetanilide

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image: question]

I figured the answer would be option (B) as the group attached to the benzene ring is *ortho*- and  *para*- directing.

I thought $\ce{FeBr3}$ would be used in electrophilic aromatic substitution.

However, the model answer to the question is (D).

Is this correct? If so, what makes it possible?

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/61123/bromination-of-acetanilide

Answer (score 4):

This is a classic $\alpha$-bromination of a carbonyl. You can achieve this with an electrophilic source of bromine like in the reaction conditions provided or something like *N*-bromosuccinimide.

The reason you're not getting the EAS product is because that's a much higher energy pathway since you need to temporarily break aromaticity. Given more time, heat, and bromine, you can probably get the ortho- and para- products, but you will still $\alpha$-brominate on the amide *first*.

Answer (score 4):

There are two competing mechanisms.

---

The first one is the electrophilic aromatic substitution which you expected:

[image: EAS mechanism]

The rate-determining step is presumably the first step, where a relatively unstable [arenium ion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arenium_ion) is formed.

---

The second one is the [carbonyl alpha-substitution reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonyl_alpha-substitution_reactions):

[image: CASR mechanism]

I failed to identify the rate determining step because of the coordination of the Lewis acid $\ce{FeBr3}$.

---

Therefore, the second mechanism occurs at a higher rate compared to the first mechanism, so more 2-bromo-*N*-phenylacetamide is produced per unit time, which makes it the **major product**.

Comment: You should have the Lewis acid $\ce{FeBr3}$ coordinate to the carbonyl oxygen before tautormerising. And the amide group is *meta*-directing, not *ortho/para* afaik. Apart from that, this is practically spot-on.

Comment: @Jan AFAIK, the amide is *meta*-directing when the carbon in the amide is attached to the benzene, and *ortho*/*para*-directing when the nitrogen is attached to the benzene instead...

Comment: @Jan is it alright now? The coordination is amazing.

Comment: Curly arrows in second step are wrong.

Comment: @orthocresol I have fixed it now.

Comment: Step 3 as drawn (i.e., the actual bromination) is most likely the r.d.s.

Comment: @Zhe I think the bromine, under the presence of the catalyst, has already been significantly polarized up to that step, lowering the r.d.s.

Comment: Yes, but that's still the intermolecular step, and you're competing with what? Enolization?

Comment: Also, I'm not criticizing your answer. I already up-voted it. :)

Comment: Not sure why you drew an ortho substitution for the EAS example, wouldn't para be far more abundant due to the steric blocking by the acetyl group?